# OpenAPI Swagger UI redirects https to http

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui

Hi I'm using `springdoc-openapi-ui` with version 1.3.3

When I hit [**https**://myappserver-01.com/swagger-ui.html](https://myappserver-01.com/swagger-ui.html) URL it is always redirecting to [**http**://myappserver-01.com/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config](http://myappserver-01.com/swagger-ui/index.html?configUrl=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config)

Basically it is changing from https to http as it redirects. Is there any way I can retain https?

Comment: I just ran into the same problem with `springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.5`.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot 2 you can try adding

~~~
server:
  tomcat:
    use-relative-redirects: true
~~~

Because springdoc-opani uses the `redirect:` keyword tomcat will create a location header that starts with http. By using relative redirects you are independent and can prevent the https downgrade.